# Javascript - Button visible when has content in a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like that when the user inserts information in a specific input text, another element becomes visible. My question looks study, but I'm new on JavaScript world, and I have tried searching on Google and here but I wasn't able to find anything.

Check out my code:

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="pwInput">
  <a href="#" class="hide">Show password</a>
</div>
```

What I want is that the "Show password" anchor only shows when the password input has content inside.

Comment: The correct tag is `<label>`, not `<lable>`.

Comment: So add an event handler to it when the person types..... than remove the class.

Answer (score 4):

Super simple option... use the *input* event handler on the `<input>` to toggle a class on it. You can then use an adjacent-sibling selector in your CSS to show or hide the `<a>`.

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.has-input + .hide {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="pwInput" 
         oninput="this.classList.toggle('has-input', this.value.trim())">
  <a href="#" class="hide">Show password</a>
</div>
```

If you're not a fan of inline event handlers, this is the unobtrusive equivalent

```js
document.getElementById('pwInput').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('has-input', this.value.trim())
}, false)
```

---

Note, the `force` option on `classList.toggle()` [doesn't work in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility). If you need to support it, try something like

```js
this.classList[this.value.trim() ? 'add' : 'remove']('has-input')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in JavaScript:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    if (document.getElementById("pwInput").value != "") {
        document.querySelector(".hide").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector(".hide").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="pwInput">
  <a href="#" class="hide">Show password</a>
</div>
```

This will check every keydown if the input has any content, plus it'll work both ways e.g. if the user deletes the password then the anchor will go away.

Comment: _"if the user deletes the password then the anchor will go away'_ <- doesn't look like this is the case as there's nothing removing the inline style

Comment: Oh yes, sorry - I missed that `else if`. Fixed now.

Comment: Just `else` should suffice

Comment: Oh yes, because you have either `""` or `"whatever"`; no in-between. Fixed

Comment: Wouldn't it be more logical to do your conditional test `onkeydown` rather than every "millisecond"?